# Is there a way to merge my current dev branch to a staging branch as a step?

Tags: git, git-merge

I have git installed on the machine but I keep getting the error message below when I try to run "git fetch origin/staging" in a shell script:

```
git fetch origin/staging
fatal: 'origin/staging' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
script returned exit code 128
```

My next shell commands would be

```
git checkout origin/staging
git merge dev
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did the trick! The first step checks out the staging branch. The second step merges dev to staging. And the last step pushes staging to origin.

```
stage('Merge') {
      steps {
        git branch: 'staging', credentialsId: 'a-long-id', url: 'https://test@bitbucket.org/project/myrepo.git'
        sh 'git merge dev'
        sh 'git push origin staging'
      }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> fatal: 'origin/staging' does not appear to be a git repository

Note that `origin/staging` refers to a remote tracking branch. The error message tells you that [`git fetch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch) requires the name of a remote instead. So try

```
git fetch origin
```

Then you should do

```
git checkout staging
```

which creates a new local branch named `staging` which points at the same commit as the remote tracking branch `origin/staging`. Then you can do

```
git merge dev
```

just as you have.

Comment: checking out the staging branch gives an error:


git checkout staging
error: pathspec 'staging' did not match any file(s) known to git.
script returned exit code 1


Ive tried git checkout origin staging as well.

Comment: @GaganSingh Does your bitbucket repo have a branch named `staging`?

Answer (score 2):

`git fetch` is not expecting a `<branch>` as first parameter, but a `<remote>` instead, so you could just

```
git fetch origin
```

(check the [doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch) for details)

However, you *can* fetch specifically for a branch on a remote, but you'll have to be explicit on the remote or your branch will be assumed as remote itself :

```
git fetch origin staging
```

*(Note that we used here the name of the branch itself, not* `origin/staging`*, the name of the remote-tracking branch which tracks it in your repository)*